DBT not creating a table when `dbt run` is executed
I'm trying to run the default configuration that gets generated from dbt init, that looks something like this:
schema.yml
version: 2

models:
  - name: my_first_dbt_model
    description: "A starter dbt model"
    columns:
      - name: id
        description: "The primary key for this table"
        data_tests:
          - unique
          - not_null

  - name: my_second_dbt_model
    description: "A starter dbt model"
    columns:
      - name: id
        description: "The primary key for this table"
        data_tests:
          - unique
          - not_null

first_model
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

with source_data as (

    select 1 as id
    union all
    select null as id

)

select *
from source_data
where id is not null

second_model
select *
from {{ ref('my_first_dbt_model') }}
where id = 1

When I execute this configuration via dbt run I see the following output:
22:21:18  1 of 6 START sql table model my_schemas.my_first_dbt_model ................ [RUN]
22:21:18  1 of 6 OK created sql table model my_schemas.my_first_dbt_model ........... [SELECT 1 in 0.06s]
22:21:18  2 of 6 START test not_null_my_first_dbt_model_id ............................... [RUN]
22:21:18  3 of 6 START test unique_my_first_dbt_model_id ................................. [RUN]
22:21:18  3 of 6 PASS unique_my_first_dbt_model_id ....................................... [PASS in 0.04s]
22:21:18  2 of 6 PASS not_null_my_first_dbt_model_id ..................................... [PASS in 0.04s]
22:21:18  4 of 6 START sql table model my_schemas.my_second_dbt_model ............... [RUN]
22:21:18  4 of 6 OK created sql table model my_schemas.my_second_dbt_model .......... [SELECT 1 in 0.02s]
22:21:18  5 of 6 START test not_null_my_second_dbt_model_id .............................. [RUN]
22:21:18  6 of 6 START test unique_my_second_dbt_model_id ................................ [RUN]
22:21:18  5 of 6 PASS not_null_my_second_dbt_model_id .................................... [PASS in 0.03s]
22:21:18  6 of 6 PASS unique_my_second_dbt_model_id ...................................... [PASS in 0.03s]
22:21:18
22:21:18  Finished running 2 table models, 4 data tests in 0 hours 0 minutes and 0.23 seconds (0.23s).
22:21:18
22:21:18  Completed successfully
22:21:18
22:21:18  Done. PASS=6 WARN=0 ERROR=0 SKIP=0 TOTAL=6

However when I auth to the postgres database DBT is using, I see the following:
my_database=# \d+
Did not find any relations.


Try \d+ *.*. My guess is you don't have search_path set to cover 'my_schemas'.

That was it! I totally missed the fact that it was using a postgres schema. Thank you!
